# Retrive just one array

Tags: java, arrays, jtable

I have the following method

```
  public Object[] loopthroughTables(){
       Object[] tables  = new Object[1]; 
       tables[0] = tableR;
       tables[1] = tableB15;
      return tables;  
    }
```

I want to retrieve just tableR from my calling method

```
loopthroughTables();
```

my current setup is

```
Object[][] data = getTableData(tableR); //create an array of the table data
```

but i want to do something like

```
Object[][] data = getTableData(loopthroughTables()); //create an array of the table data
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loopthroughTables()` as the array reference it is.

```
Object tableR = loopthroughTables()[0];
```

Another way would be to change your method return type to `Object` and to return `tableR`

---

### WARNING

new Object[1] creates a new array of `Object` that can contain one and only `Object` object. So your code will throw an `Exception` at runtime because of `tables[1] = tableB15;`